# XPath Select if value of a node equals a specific text

Tags: c#, xpath

I have an OIOXML, which contains AllowanceCharge, and I need to figure out, if I have to add or subtract the amount.
It depends on the ID, whether I need to add or subtract, as I need the text to be `rabat` in order to subtract.

An example of some of the OIOXML

```
<Invoice>
  ...
  <com:AllowanceCharge>
    <com:ID>Gebyr</com:ID>
    <com:ChargeIndicator>true</com:ChargeIndicator>
    <com:MultiplierReasonCode>Leveringstillæg</com:MultiplierReasonCode>
    <com:MultiplierFactorQuantity unitCode="stk" unitCodeListAgencyID="n/a">0.00</com:MultiplierFactorQuantity>
    <com:AllowanceChargeAmount currencyID="DKK">29.00</com:AllowanceChargeAmount>
  </com:AllowanceCharge>
  ...
</Invoice>
```

I have created support for OIOXML, which send it using `true` and `false`, so I want to know, if I can select it out as `true` or `false`.

The start of the XPath looks like

```
/*/com:AllowanceCharge/com:ID[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'rabat']
```

But is it possible to select the value out as `true`, if the text is `rabat` otherwise `false` as text

Comment: What's the question here? and what's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: If is is possible to select the value out as true or false

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap you XPath with the Boolean function as follows:

```
boolean(/*/com:AllowanceCharge/com:ID[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'rabat'])
```

And to use the above one use [XPathEvaluate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675(v=vs.110).aspx). Hope this helps...